# Adobe suite to create a high definition 3D cube animation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, animation

I'm looking to try and create something along the quality of this video below:
http://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-1992226-stock-footage-red-cube.html?src=search/H2Qpzpwk6MCZPa0pfA2U0g:1:25/3p

Now, creating the 3D object I can probably do in Photoshop, but wouldn't the frame rate be too low for something like this? Also, could it be exported as an MP4, rather than an animated gif?

Failing that, would anybody care to recommend any other solutions to this inside the Adobe CC suite? Or would I need to purchase different software altogether in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can do this in photoshop if you can make the model elsewhere, you can also do this in After effects. I would seriously consider Blender, Maya, Max or Modo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be a lot better off probably using Blender, Maya, or After Effects + Cinema4D for this. But if you are confident you can create the object in Photoshop than frame rate shouldn't be an issue. Adobe Photoshop has decent video controls now and renders as .mp4. Additionally, you could use Adobe Media Encoder if you need to convert from .mp4 to some other format.